# Errors On Launching Browser And Going To Website (In Selenium Webdriver)

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#

[image: Amended Code For Launching Browser In VS 2015][image: [Screen Shot Of Error List - 02][1].]

@alecxe - I have edited the code. But, I still get errors. Thanks very much for your help.

=========================================================================

I have done this several times before and it has worked. But for some reason, it is not working. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 (Community Edition - if that [image: Screen Shot Of Error List -03] helps. I have downloaded the necessary libraries and added the required dependencies in MS/Visual Studio. I have also added a picture of the error list.

Here is the code:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace CV_Library_P.OM_09_2017
{
    class Valid_Username_Valid_Password
    {

        //Instantiate Firefox Driver
        var driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        FirefoxDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.cv-library.co.uk/candidate/login");

        //Enter User Name - Email Address
        var user = driver.FindElement(By.Id("cand-login-left"));
        user.SendKeys("testsuccess761@gmail.com");

            //Enter Password - Account Pasword
            var pass = driver.FindElement(By.Id("cand-login-left"));
        pass.SendKeys("p@55word123!");

            //Click on Login button
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("cand-login-left")).Click();
```

[image: Error List From Launching Browser And Going To Website]

Comment: I installed MS/Visual Studio 2015 on another PC, and, I was able to do a successful build of the code. But, I got the error message: openqa.selenium.webdriverexception 
​

{"unable to find a matching set of capabilities"}​​

My google search of the error indicates that it is likely a compatibility issue between Selenium Webdriver and Firefox.

I will try and trouble shoot by running Chrome Driver instead.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**1:**  Your first error says that: **Invalid token class/interface/member declaration**
Ans: You have missed basic concept of **Encapsulation**

- You have not declared the main method.
- Every code should be capsulated within the: Class--> Method-->Data

**2:** Error Method should have a return type.
This error occurs because you have not declared any method within your class.

**3:** If you are using Selenium 3.0 or greater version then you must have to initialize Firefox-Geckodriver path in your code. [Check here, if don't know how to do this.](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/26328/what-is-geckodriver-how-to-use-it-in-selenium-webdriver/26333#26333)

**4:** Instead of `FirefoxDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("")` use:

```
driver.get("Your AppURL")
```