# Mozilla browser open issue in the Selenium Webdriver

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, firefoxdriver

Getting below issue while opening Mozilla Firefox browser using selenium webdriver. Browser opens for just few seconds (1-2 seconds) and it gets closes automatically.

**Error:**

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException:      Build
info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15
17:00:58' System info: host: 'sevenbits-HP-Compaq-8100-Elite-SFF-PC',
ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
'4.4.0-31-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_171' Driver info:
driver.version: FirefoxDriver
```

Answer (score 1):

For Selenium 2.53, use Firefox 45.0.2. It will work perfectly.

You can also try upgrading to Selenium 3, but then you will need to upgrade the Firefox Version above 47 and also need to use GeckoDriver with it.

Both configurations work properly for Automation. You can choose whichever you are comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

This may because of the selenium version you are using. Update the selenium version to the latest version with the updated geckodriver to match the selenium version and firefox browser version. Try this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Browser Version. 
Selenium Webdriver version 2.53 is not compatible with Mozilla Firefox version 47.0+

Use GeckoDriver if you want to run automated tests on Mozilla Firefox version 47.0+
How to use `GeckoDriver` - [What is geckodriver? How to use it in Selenium Webdriver?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/26328/what-is-geckodriver-how-to-use-it-in-selenium-webdriver)